Are there any remedies for an ulcerated skin cancer foul smell?
I have a 15 year old Havanese with a large ulcerated squamous cell carcinoma on her leg. We took her to the vet. She put her on an oral antibiotic and a topical antibiotic for infection and some medicated wipes. She said that the only options for her are surgery or radiation. However, given her age, she would not put her through either of these options. Since the vet visit, the mass on her leg has grown and the area has the most foul smell. I clean the area twice a day and the odor is still there. Is there anybody who can recommend anything for the smell? I’m not putting her through surgery or radiation. She is not in pain, no limping, still eating and drinking etc. I just want to try to get rid of the odor!! Any ideas??

Some peole with end-stage cancer have the same problem and AFAIK the best solution humanity has come up with is a mix of essential oils. Unfortunately all of the essential oils recommended for humans in this scenario are toxic for dogs. Sorry.
